# MySQL - OPTIMIZE TABLE for partitions

Tags: mysql, optimization

I would like to perform OPTIMIZE TABLE opearation , this table is a partitioned table.

Which method can be better in this scenario:

1. > OPTIMIZE TABLE tblname;

or

2. > ALTER TABLE tblname OPTIMIZE PARTITION p0, p1;

Answer (score 1):

From the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-maintenance.html):

> Some MySQL storage engines, including InnoDB, do not support
>   per-partition optimization; in these cases, ALTER TABLE ... OPTIMIZE
>   PARTITION rebuilds the entire table.

There is a reason to optimize separately each partition, in order to avoid locking and performance issues. However, if you are using Innodb, you will get the following warning:

```
Table does not support optimize on partitions. All partitions will be rebuilt and analyzed
```

Which basically makes the `OPTIMIZE PARTITION` syntax useless. Also, if you only have 2 partitions (p0 and p1), you are basically executing `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.

My questions is why you are running optimize to start with and if it is justified? You should also add the MySQL version and engine used. In any case, you are probably executing the first option implicitly or explicitly.

Comment: Actually our application executes lot of DML statements and once a week we purge the data so we need to shrink ".ibd" file size. 
I think it's good practice to do OPTIMIZE once in 15 days. 
MySQL v5.5.30 and InnoDB I prefer first option anyway but if I can do OPTIMIZE at paritition level will it reduce overhead on server locking, speed etc.. ?